# Why does n-reduction not apply to filter even in the following example?

Tags: haskell

I am following ['Learn Haskell Fast and Hard'](http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/Haskell-the-Hard-Way/) and I was able to follow most of it, but I have two questions for the following code sample.

1. In the first function, why don't I need `l` but in the second version I do need `l`?
2. In `evenSum1`, when the function is called recursively will `filter` be called on the list again and again or will `filter` be called only once on the first call?

.

```
evenSum = accumSum 0 
    where 
        accumSum n [] = n
        accumSum n (x:xs) =
                        if even x
                                then accumSum (n+x) xs
                                else accumSum n xs

evenSum1 l = mysum 0 (filter even l)
    where
        mysum n [] = n
        mysum n (x:xs) = mysum (n+x) xs
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually drop of the `l` in the second example too, but you need to switch to what is called [*point free notation*](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree) and use the function composition operator `(.)`:

```
evenSum1 = mysum 0 . filter even
    where
        mysum n [] = n
        mysum n (x:xs) = mysum (n + x) xs
```

And in `evenSum1`, the `filter even` function will only be called once.  What happens is that `filter even` runs out the list passed in, then the output of that is passed to `mysum 0`.

---

### A quick primer on point free notation

Say you have a function `add`:

```
add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add x y = x + y
```

And then you want to make a function `add5` that always adds 5 to an `Int`.  You could do it as

```
add5 :: Int -> Int
add5 y = add 5 y
```

But since functions are first class objects in Haskell and we can partially apply a function, this is equivalent to saying

```
add5 :: Int -> Int
add5 = add 5
```

Another way to look at it is to add some optional parentheses to the type signature of `add`:

```
add :: Int -> (Int -> Int)
add x y = x + y
```

Written like this, we can say that `add` is a function that accepts a single `Int` argument and returns a new function of `Int -> Int`.  So if we give `add` a single `Int`, we get a new function back.  This is also what lets us write expressions like

```
filter even list
```

Instead of

```
filter (\x -> even x) list
```

A good rule of thumb for point-free notation is that variables can be dropped off the end turning the last `$` into a `.`:

```
f x y = h x $ g y
f x   = h x . g

f x y z = h x $ g y $ j z
f x y   = h x $ g y . j
```

This doesn't always work with multi-argument functions:

```
f x y = h $ g x y
```

Is not the same as

```
f = h . g
```

Because `h . g` won't type check.  This is because of implicit parentheses:

```
f x y = h $ (g x) y
f x   = h . (g x)
```

And now there's parentheses in the way from being able to drop the `x` argument.

Also, keep in mind that `f x y = h (g x y)` is equivalent to `f x y = h $ g x y`, so you can usually turn the outermost parentheses into a `$` instead, potentially letting you eta-reduce and change the `$` to a `.`.  If all this seems confusing, you can also grab the [pointfree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree) package off hackage, which contains a command line tool for automatically performing eta-reductions for you.

Comment: I am kind of lost on (\x -> even x). what is the use of \ in my code evenSum5 = foldl (\x y -> x + y) 0 . filter even

Comment: The ```\``` denotes a lambda function or an anonymous function, because if you squint it kind of looks like a `λ` symbol.  When you use a function like `even` in `filter even`, this is equivalent to creating a lambda function with an explicit argument: `filter (\x -> even x)`.  And in fact, GHC performs this kind of transformation when compiling your code.  Not having to use lambda functions everywhere is just syntactic sugar.  With `foldl (\x y -> x + y) 0 . filter even`, you could even write it as `foldl (+) 0 . filter even`, since your arguments are in the same order.

Comment: If you had `foldl (\x y -> y + x) 0 . filter even`, this wouldn't be the same as `foldl (+) 0 . filter even` because the order of arguments is flipped, but it would be equivalent to `foldl (flip (+)) . filter even`.